# println vs System.out.println in Scala

Tags: scala, compatibility, println

I always thought that `Predef.println` was merely a shortcut for `System.out.println`, but apparently I am mistaken, since it doesn't seem to use `System.out` at all. Why is that so? And how can I do the "redirecting" of `System.out` below in Scala?

```
scala> val baos = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
baos: java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream = 

scala> val ps = new java.io.PrintStream(baos)
ps: java.io.PrintStream = java.io.PrintStream@6c5ac4

scala> System.setOut(ps)

scala> println("hello")
hello

scala> new String(baos.toByteArray)
res2: java.lang.String = ""

scala> System.out.println("hello")

scala> new String(baos.toByteArray)
res7: java.lang.String = 
"hello
"
```

Comment: See https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4793.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`Predef.println` is shortcut for `Console.println` and you can use `Console.setOut` or `Console.withOut` for redirecting.

Also, `Console.setOut` only affects the current thread while System.setOut
affects the whole JVM. Additionally Scala 2.9 `repl` evaluates each line in its own thread, so `Console.setOut` is not usable there.

```
scala> val baos = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
baos: java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream = 

scala> Console.withOut(baos)(print("hello"))

scala> println(baos)
hello
```

Comment: 'without' sounds somehow wrong, even the big O doesn't heal it. :)

Comment: @userunknown Agreed. To make matters even worse, there's even a `Console.withIn`.